# Auto Login into DNN

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, autologin

I am trying to develop an application in that i want auto login in DNN application.means in my application a login page will be there when i enter my username and password i have to redirect the user to DNN Site.Can Any one help me out in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

you would have to develop your own authentication provider that can accept the information you are providing to login that person. See here for more info on authentication providers: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Authentication_Providers.aspx